# Reddit api request 403 error

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, reddit

Im having an issue where I have a good oauth token with bearer type but whenever I try to make an api call it throws me a 403 Forbidden message. The call is to just get the posts from a sub reddit page(i.e. https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming.json) but with the oauth base url. Not sure if I'm missing header I need or something. Someone please help.

ServiceGenerator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    private static final String OAUTH_BASE_URL = "https://oauth.reddit.com/";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXX";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient;
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder;

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final Context context) {
        httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(OAUTH_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        final String token_type = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("token_type", "");
        final String refresh_token = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("refresh_token", "");
        final String access_token = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("access_token", "");

        if(!access_token.equals("")) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Intercepting request: " + request.url());

                    if(response.header("No-Authentication") == null){
                        response = response.newBuilder()
                                .addHeader("User-Agent", "my user agent")
                                .addHeader("Authorization", token_type + " " + access_token)
                                .build();
                    }

                    return response;
                }
            });

            httpClient.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                    if(responseCount(response) >= 2) {
                        // If both the original call and the call with refreshed token failed,
                        // it will probably keep failing, so don't try again.
                        return null;
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing Token");

                    String credentials = CLIENT_ID + ":";
                    String encodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                    // We need a new client, since we don't want to make another call using our client with access token
                    RedditService tokenClient = createService(RedditService.class);
                    Call<AccessToken> call = tokenClient.refreshToken("Basic " + encodedCredentials, "refresh_token", refresh_token);
                    try {
                        retrofit2.Response<AccessToken> tokenResponse = call.execute();
                        if(tokenResponse.code() == 200) {
                            AccessToken newToken = tokenResponse.body();
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("logged_in", true).apply();
                            prefs.edit().putString("token_type", newToken.token_type).apply();
                            prefs.edit().putString("access_token", newToken.access_token).apply();
                            prefs.edit().putString("refresh_token", newToken.refresh_token).apply();

                            return response.request().newBuilder()
                                    .header("Authorization", newToken.token_type + " " + newToken.access_token)
                                    .build();
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    private static int responseCount(Response response) {
        int result = 1;
        while ((response = response.priorResponse()) != null) {
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Client (tried with and without .json):

```
public interface RedditService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/v1/access_token")
    @Headers("No-Authentication: true")
    Call<AccessToken> getLoginToken(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                    @Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
                                    @Field("code") String code,
                                    @Field("redirect_uri") String redirect_uri);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/v1/access_token")
    @Headers("No-Authentication: true")
    Call<AccessToken> refreshToken(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                                   @Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
                                   @Field("refresh_token") String redirect_uri);

    @GET("/r/{subreddit}/{sort}")
    Call<Page> getSubredditPage(@Path("subreddit") String subreddit,
                                @Path("sort") String sort,
                                @Query("after") String after);
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here's the headers that are being sent along with the request

```
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 20:58:55 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-ord1733-ORD
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1480107535.759884,VS0,VE19
Set-Cookie: loid=omeUS2oZLIDWukuAYK; Domain=reddit.com; Max-Age=63071999; Path=/;  secure
Set-Cookie: loidcreated=1480107535000; Domain=reddit.com; Max-Age=63071999; Path=/;  secure
Server: snooserv
Authorization: bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
User-Agent: my-user-agent
```

Comment: Have you solved this ?